'Unsupported file' error when uploading a file via streaming via the OpenAI API
I tried to upload a file via the OpenAI API with a file path, and it worked properly, saving with the '.md' extension in storage.
Then I uploaded a file with streaming and the file has been saved as 'upload' without any extension in the API storage.
When I tried to retrieve the data in that case I got this error:
raise self._make_status_error_from_response(err.response) from None
openai.BadRequestError: Error code: 400 - {'error': {'message': 'Files with extensions [none] are not supported for 
retrieval. See https://platform.openai.com/docs/assistants/tools/supported-files', 'type': 'invalid_request_error',
'param': None, 'code': 'unsupported_file'}}

I assume it is related to the idea that OpenAI doesn't recognize the '.md' extension in the file name (the file name in that case is 'upload').
this is my upload part of code:
def create_file(client, file_stream, file_name):
    file = client.files.create(
        file=file_stream,
        purpose='assistants'
    )
    return file.id,

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?
I haven't seen any way to add file name directly here:
def create_file(client, file_stream, file_name):
    file = client.files.create(
        file=file_stream,
        purpose='assistants'
    )
    return file.id,

Uploading with file path (what upload to the storage with the correct name) is not relevant for me because I want to get the file through API call, so I assume I have to send it in streaming.
